# Reroute only Firebase analytics to another account

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

Please, don't throw stones. I have basically the same question as this: [Is it possible to use FCM and Firebase Analytics in different google account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47966428/is-it-possible-to-use-fcm-and-firebase-analytics-in-different-google-account) which doesn't have any answers.

I use quite a lot of Firebase features in the Android app I'm currently developing (FCM, Auth, etc.), but now the management wants Analytics in a separate account created specifically for Marketing. Is it possible to move just Analytics there or do I have to move all of the features to the Marketing account as well?

Comment: I would send an email off to the Firebase team asking about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote to Firebase support, and here's their answer:

> Hello there,
>
> Thanks for reaching out.
>
> Analytics data cannot be migrated from one account to another. You
>   also cannot export and import historical data with Google Analytics
>   for Firebase.
>
> There are two way you could share the Analytics data to your Marketing
>   team
>
> 1. You can [link your account to BigQuery](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en) and then use [DataStudio](https://www.google.com/analytics/data-studio/) to make custom reports which can be used by your Marketing team. Take
>      note that you can only export data to BigQuery starting the date of
>      the linkage so you cannot get BigQuery data for your previous data.
> 2. You can give your Marketing team's account a Viewer's access to your Firebase project. This way they can only see the data but will
>      not be able to edit or change anything in your project. You can see
>      this [documentation](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7000272?hl=en) for your reference.
>
> Regards, xxx

I discussed the issue with my superior, and he agreed to giving the Marketing team Viewer's access to the original project, so that's what I'll do.

Hope it helps anyone else who's having similar issues.